# Manually activate Drill down in Highcharts chart by clicking on another chart

Tags: javascript, angularjs, highcharts

I'm using highcharts to draw two charts in angular(but I don;t think that is important or this problem) - pie chart and bar chart. I have two charts defined and I want to trigger drill down in bar chart when I click on pie chart. Also, drill down should be preformed for same data. 
These are chart settings:

```
import Highcharts from 'highcharts/highstock';

export const MEDIA_CHART = {
chart: {
  height: 350,
  type: 'pie',
  width: 300
},
drilldown: {
 allowPointDrilldown: true
},
legend: {
 borderWidth: 0,
 enabled: true,
 symbolRadius: 0,
 title: {
  text: ''
},
useHTML: true,
/*eslint-disable*/
labelFormatter: function () {
  return '<div style="max-width:150px;"><span style="width:100%;display:block;text-align:center;">' + this.name + '</span><span>' + Highcharts.numberFormat(this.y, 2, ',', '.') + '€</span></div>';
}
/*eslint-enable*/
},
plotOptions: {
 pie: {
  center: ['48%', '42%'],
  showInLegend: true
 },
series: {
  allowPointSelect: true,
  cursor: 'pointer',
  /*eslint-disable*/
  events: {
    click: function (event) {
      console.log(TACTIC_CHART.chart.drilldownLevels.length);
    }
  },
  /*eslint-enable*/
  dataLabels: {
    enabled: true,
    format: '<b>{point.name}</b>: {point.percentage:.1f} %'
  }
}
},
 series: [{
 size: '95%',
 innerSize: '60%'

}],
tooltip: {
borderWidth: 0,
backgroundColor: '#37474F',
headerFormat: '',
pointFormat: '{point.name}: {point.y:,.2f}€',
style: {
  color: '#fff',
  padding: 0,
  fontWeight: 700
},
useHTML: true
}
};

export const TACTIC_CHART = {
chart: {
 type: 'bar',
 height: '100%'
},
colors: ['#969696', '#F1292E', '#A0CB0E'],
drilldown: {
  allowPointDrilldown: true
},
xAxis: {
title: {
  text: null
},
 type: 'category'
},
yAxis: {
 min: 0,
 title: {
  text: 'Budget €',
  align: 'high'
},
labels: {
  overflow: 'justify'
}
},
tooltip: {
  enabled: true,
  borderWidth: 0,
  backgroundColor: '#37474F',
  headerFormat: '',
  pointFormat: '{series.name}: {point.y:,.2f}€',
  style: {
  color: '#fff',
  padding: 0,
  fontWeight: 700
},
  useHTML: true,
  valueSuffix: ' €'
},
title: {
align: 'left'
},
plotOptions: {
bar: {
  dataLabels: {
    enabled: true,
    /*eslint-disable*/
    formatter:  function () {
      return Highcharts.numberFormat(this.y, 2, ',', '.') + '€';
    }
    /*eslint-enable*/
  }
 }
},
legend: {
  enabled: true,
  layout: 'horizontal',
  align: 'center',
  verticalAlign: 'top',
  floating: true,
  borderWidth: 1,
  backgroundColor: '#FFFFFF',
  shadow: true
}
};
```

In this part I catch click on pie chart:

```
events: {
    click: function (event) {
      console.log(TACTIC_CHART.chart.drilldownLevels.length);
    }
  },
```

I tried to get this but I get error `can't get length of undefined`. I tried every possible solution that I found, but without any luck. Problem is that I need to preserve data for bar chart, so I can't redraw it, I need to activate drill down if it's possible. Thanks everyone for help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can call internal function `Point.doDrilldown()` on specific point of another chart in `drilldown` event and `Chart.drillUp()` on `drillup` event. Also, remember to create some flag variable to prevent infinite loop. Take a look at the below example I prepared for you. In case of any question, feel free to ask.

API Reference:
http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/chart.events.drilldown
http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/chart.events.drillup

Example:
http://jsfiddle.net/048kne3c/

Comment: Hi @d_paul, this is exactly what I looked for! Let me just try it in next few days, since I moved to another urgent task, and as soon I tested it out, if everything is ok, I'll accept your answer. Sorry for the delay, but that's the job :)

Comment: No problem, glad it helps (or at least looks helpful :)).

Comment: Hi @d_paul I managed to almost make it to work. I get `Cannot read property 'levelNumber' of undefined` on drillUp. Do you know what that can be? Thanks for all help! :)

Comment: This is what I missed in your code. Don't know why, but this worked `chart.addSingleSeriesAsDrilldown(e.point, series[0]);` Thanks for help! :)